# failure of code with Helmholtz equation with point source

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I am new to the finite elements package in *Mathematica*. I have a system of equations, one of which is a Helmholtz equation with a point source in the interior of a bounded domain. The following is the code I've attempted to use:

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> {{-0.05, -0.1}, {0.2, -0.1}, {0.2, 0.1}, {-0.05, 0.1},
    {0.1, 0}, {0.11, 0}, {0.11, 0.03}, {0.1, 0.03}, {0, 0}},
  "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}]}]
%["Wireframe"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
Show[
 mesh["Wireframe"],
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}]]
sol = NDSolve[{-D[u[x, y], x, x] - D[u[x, y], y, y] - u[x, y] == 0,
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == 0 && y == 0],
    u[x, 0.1] == 0,
    Derivative[1, 0][u][-0.05, y] == 0,
    Derivative[0, 1][u][x, -0.1] == 0,
    Derivative[1, 0][u][0.2, y] == 0},
   u, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
```

Error messages appear stating that the first x-derivative is not a polynomial and that the dependent variable `u` is not linear. What is wrong here?

Comment: I think this does what you want:sol = NDSolve[{-D[u[x, y], x, x] - D[u[x, y], y, y] - u[x, y] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == 0 && y == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == .1]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh] I have the impression your boundary conditions are redundant since the rhs of the pde is 0

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
(*
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
\[CapitalOmega]=Rectangle[{-0.05,-0.1},{0.2,0.1}];
mesh=ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega],"IncludePoints"\[Rule]{{0,0}}];
*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{-D[u[x, y], x, x] - D[u[x, y], y, y] - 
      u[x, y] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == 0 && y == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, y == 0.1]
    }, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
sol[0, 0]
0.9999999999999986`
```

Comment: Thanks to User 21 for the above suggestion. It works.

Comment: @RJR, no worries.